# Sum up unique item combinations in an Array swift 4

Tags: swift

I create the following object:

```
class Order {
    var productId : Int
    var userId : Int
    var qty : Int
    init(productId: Int, userId: Int, qty: Int) {
        self.productId = productId
        self.userId = userId
        self.qty = qty
    }
}
```

Then I created the following Array:

```
var arrayOfOrders = [Order(productId: 1, userId: 1, qty: 5),
                     Order(productId: 1, userId: 2, qty: 10),
                     Order(productId: 1, userId: 2, qty: 15),
                     Order(productId: 2, userId: 1, qty: 20),
                     Order(productId: 2, userId: 1, qty: 10),
                     Order(productId: 2, userId: 2, qty: 5),
                     Order(productId: 3, userId: 1, qty: 15),
                     Order(productId: 3, userId: 1, qty: 5)]
```

I need to get the unique combination of productID and userID and sum up qty in a new [Order] array like this:

[image]

Is it possible to use higher order functions like reduce or map? Any other simple approach would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I would use a Set for this

Comment: why is not `{productId 3, userId 1, qty 25}`...? that seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct Key: Hashable
{
    var userId: Int
    var productId: Int
}

// 1. Group by Key (userId, productId)
let grouped = Dictionary(grouping: arrayOfOrders) { o in
    Key(userId: o.userId, productId: o.productId)
}

// 2. Add up each group's quantity
let summed = grouped.map { group -> Order in
    let qty = group.value.reduce(0) { (qty,order) in
        qty + order.qty
    }
    return Order(productId: group.key.productId,
          userId: group.key.userId,
          qty: qty)
}
```

Note the similarity to what you would do using SQL GROUP BY/aggregate functions  like so:

```
SELECT UserId, ProductId, SUM(Qty) 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY UserId, ProductId
```

Comment: I was trying to find a way to make this work with a tuple as the key, but wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way (perhaps a bit silly). First, change your class to a Hashable struct (this is Swift 4.2 or later) where equality does not depend on `qty`, like this:

```
struct Order : Hashable {
    static func ==(lhs:Order,rhs:Order) -> Bool {
        return lhs.productId == rhs.productId && lhs.userId == rhs.userId
    }
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        productId.hash(into:&hasher)
        userId.hash(into:&hasher)
    }
    // ... and the rest is as before
}
```

Now put the orders into a Set, thus uniquing them, while changing the `qty` to `0`:

```
var set = Set(arrayOfOrders.map { order -> Order in
    var order = order
    order.qty = 0
    return order
})
```

Now it's a fast single pass to total the `qty` values into the Set:

```
arrayOfOrders.forEach { order in
    if var totalOrder = set.remove(order) {
        totalOrder.qty += order.qty
        set.insert(totalOrder)
    }
}
```

Result (`set`):

```
[Order(productId: 1, userId: 2, qty: 25), 
Order(productId: 2, userId: 1, qty: 30), 
Order(productId: 1, userId: 1, qty: 5), 
Order(productId: 3, userId: 1, qty: 20), 
Order(productId: 2, userId: 2, qty: 5)]
```

Comment: I don't think this works.  If you take the OP's original dataset, your output array will be the same as the input array, because the structs include `qty`, not just `userId` and `productId`

Comment: Oh, I see, @jlew - I'll modify.

Comment: @jlew Okay, changed it. But in fact what I _really_ wanted to do (as soon as you made me see what the problem actually was) is what _you_ did, i.e. use `Dictionary(grouping:)`.